# The best way to re render a component that depends on a big array in svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I'm facing a problem with my svelte app.
The thing is I have an array that is filled from a JSON File.
The array is passed to a child component as a prop. The thing is.
I'd like to change the array contents then re render the component.
OR:
I'd like to hide the component then show it again.
The problem is, when I try to do that, the array becomes null after the component is changed for the 2nd time (Update or destroy). (only works for the first time)

See a snippet of my code:

```svelte
<script>
    import * as meca from "./meca.json";
    import AppMeca from "./AppMeca.svelte";
    
    let test1 = Object.entries(meca);
    let courses1 = test1[0][1]; //gets the array from the JSON.
    let flag = false;

    function toggleMeca() {
    flag = !flag;
    }

</script>

<button on:click={toggleMeca}> Meca </button>

{#if flag}
    <AppMeca courses={courses1} />
{/if}
```

What should I do in such situation?

==================================
Update 1:

I discovered that the problem was different than what I originally thought.
The main problem was because I don't seem to fully understand the component life cycle.

The thing is, There is an init() function inside the AppMeca.svelte component. That function did some pre-processing on the courses array.
The problem is when the component is hidden and then becomes visible, it seems like it's not created from scratch. It preserves its state before it was destroyed.
So, when the init() function is called at the beginning, it will try to process the array which was already preprocessed. So it messes up and gives an error and the app stops.

I thought that when a component is destroyed, it get's really destroyed but it seems not.
I wish I understand it correctly now xD

Main problem solved.

Comment: You don't explain what you do in `AppMeca` component but I guess that directly manipulate the prop and modify the array in place. To fix that you will need to manipulate a clone of the array. You can achieve that by declaring `course1` like that `let courses1 = [...test1[0][1]];`.

Comment: Your example code works fine with small array, you need to give more information: https://svelte.dev/repl/5827151914fe4d4d81b428e8f8c4992a?version=3.25.0

Comment: Thanks guys for trying to help. I updated the question with what I found. Problem solved.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you give an example what your `init()` is doing? I believe your problem is that you manipulate the original array like @johannchopin commented and if that’s the case it’s not related to creating/destroying the component. If the problem is really related to component’s lifecycle, it would be interesting to know more.